# Dalvik what does lfm mean

Tags: java, android, reverse-engineering, smali

I am looking at proguarded android smali code and I came across this declaration

. field public K:Lfm

What data type is K. JesusFreke does not mention it https://github.com/JesusFreke/smali/wiki/TypesMethodsAndFields

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you mean

```
.field public K:Lfm;
```

(with a semicolon at the end).

K is not a type, that's the name of the field. The type is `Lfm;`, which is the type descriptor for the class named `fm`.

Comment: I never expected to hear from the creator of smali HIMSELF. Thanks